# No module named 'serial'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyserial

I have a piece of Python3 code running on a Pi3B+ with Raspbian Buster that uses the serial library.
I imported this library with

```
sudo apt-get install python3-serial
```

The Python script is placed in .../domoticz/scripts/python/script_time_test.py to activate it every minute bij de Domoticz scheduler.

If I run this piece of code in Thonny all libraries are imported without problems. 
However if the Domotics sceduler starts the scripts, all standard libraries that come with the raspbian distribution are imported without problems but the serial library ends up with the error.
The results are the same on Stretch and Buster

The code contains at this moment only import commands

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import datetime
import json
import os.path
import shutil
import threading
import time
import serial


2019-10-29 09:37:00.162 Error: EventSystem: Failed to execute python event script "/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/python/script_time_VirtDev.py"
2019-10-29 09:37:00.162 Error: EventSystem: Traceback (most recent call last):
2019-10-29 09:37:00.162 Error: EventSystem: File "/home/pi/domoticz/scripts/python/script_time_VirtDev.py", line 10, in <module>
2019-10-29 09:37:00.162 Error: EventSystem: import serial
2019-10-29 09:37:00.162 Error: EventSystem: ImportError: No module named 'serial'
```

environment Thonny

```
environ({
'DESKTOP_SESSION': 'LXDE-pi', 
'XDG_SESSION_TYPE': 'x11', 
'INFINALITY_FT_GLOBAL_EMBOLDEN_Y_VALUE': '0', 
'THONNY_USER_DIR': '/home/pi/.thonny', 
'INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_SNAP_STEM_HEIGHT': '100', 
'SHELL': '/bin/bash', 
'INFINALITY_FT_GLOBAL_EMBOLDEN_X_VALUE': '0', 
'XDG_MENU_PREFIX': 'lxde-pi-', 
'INFINALITY_FT_USE_KNOWN_SETTINGS_ON_SELECTED_FONTS': 'true', 
'INFINALITY_FT_STEM_ALIGNMENT_STRENGTH': '25', 
'INFINALITY_FT_FILTER_PARAMS': '11 22 38 22 11', 
'INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_VERTICAL_STEM_DARKEN_STRENGTH': '25', 
'_LXSESSION_PID': '654', 
'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS': 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus', 
'INFINALITY_FT_STEM_SNAPPING_SLIDING_SCALE': '40', 
'SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN': 'gtk', 
'TEXTDOMAIN': 'Linux-PAM', 
'XDG_SESSION_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0', 
'XDG_VTNR': '7', 
'PYTHONIOENCODING': 'ASCII', 
'XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP': 'lightdm-xsession', 
'XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR': '/var/lib/lightdm/data/pi', 
'INFINALITY_FT_FRINGE_FILTER_STRENGTH': '0', 
'XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP': 'LXDE', 
'LANG': 'en_GB.UTF-8', 
'DESKTOP_STARTUP_ID': 'pcmanfm-860-raspberrypi-/usr/bin/thonny-3_TIME101146699', 
'HOME': '/home/pi', 
'GPG_AGENT_INFO': '/run/user/1000/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1', 
'XAUTHORITY': '/home/pi/.Xauthority', 
'XDG_DATA_DIRS': '/usr/local/share:/usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides:/usr/share:/usr/share/gdm:/var/lib/menu-xdg', 
'INFINALITY_FT_CHROMEOS_STYLE_SHARPENING_STRENGTH': '0', 
'SSH_AUTH_SOCK': '/tmp/ssh-SpT8Yoekyndc/agent.654', 
'INFINALITY_FT_GAMMA_CORRECTION': '0 100', 
'INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_INCREASE_GLYPH_HEIGHTS': 'true', 
'XDG_SEAT_PATH': '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0', 
'GDMSESSION': 'lightdm-xsession', 
'USER': 'pi', 
'XDG_CONFIG_DIRS': '/etc/xdg', 
'INFINALITY_FT_STEM_FITTING_STRENGTH': '25', 
'XDG_SESSION_ID': 'c1', 
'PYTHONUNBUFFERED': '1', 
'INFINALITY_FT_CONTRAST': '0', 
'SSH_AGENT_PID': '826', 
'PWD': '/home/pi', 
'INFINALITY_FT_BRIGHTNESS': '0', 
'INFINALITY_FT_BOLD_EMBOLDEN_X_VALUE': '0', 
'DISPLAY': ':0.0', 
'INFINALITY_FT_BOLD_EMBOLDEN_Y_VALUE': '0', 
'XDG_RUNTIME_DIR': '/run/user/1000', 
'INFINALITY_FT_WINDOWS_STYLE_SHARPENING_STRENGTH': '10', 
'PATH': '/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games','INFINALITY_FT_AUTOHINT_HORIZONTAL_STEM_DARKEN_STRENGTH': '10', 
'INFINALITY_FT_USE_VARIOUS_TWEAKS': 'true', 
'INFINALITY_FT_GRAYSCALE_FILTER_STRENGTH': '0', 
'XDG_CONFIG_HOME': '/home/pi/.config', 
'XDG_SEAT': 'seat0', 
'LOGNAME': 'pi'
})
```

environment Domoticz

```
environ({
'PWD': '/', 
'PATH': '/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin', 
'LANG': 'en_GB.UTF-8', 
'INVOCATION_ID': 'ed8e00a2ea7943249b6c18f40f3e9c5e', 
'JOURNAL_STREAM': '8:12744'
})
```

imported modules by the scheduled job

```
Please wait a moment while I gather a list of all available modules...

CDROM               _tracemalloc        hashlib             script_tiHR930-P3Dom
DLFCN               _warnings           heapq               script_time_VirtDev
Domoticz            _weakref            hmac                script_time_demo
DomoticzEvents      _weakrefset         html                select
IN                  abc                 http                selectors
TYPES               aifc                idlelib             shelve
__future__          antigravity         imaplib             shlex
_ast                argparse            imghdr              shutil
_bisect             array               imp                 signal
_bootlocale         ast                 importlib           site
_bz2                asynchat            inspect             sitecustomize
_codecs             asyncio             io                  smtpd
_codecs_cn          asyncore            ipaddress           smtplib
_codecs_hk          atexit              itertools           sndhdr
_codecs_iso2022     audioop             json                socket
_codecs_jp          base64              keyword             socketserver
_codecs_kr          bdb                 lib2to3             spwd
_codecs_tw          binascii            linecache           sqlite3
_collections        binhex              locale              sre_compile
_collections_abc    bisect              logging             sre_constants
_compat_pickle      builtins            lzma                sre_parse
_compression        bz2                 macpath             ssl
_crypt              cProfile            macurl2path         stat
_csv                calendar            mailbox             statistics
_ctypes             cgi                 mailcap             string
_ctypes_test        cgitb               marshal             stringprep
_curses             chunk               math                struct
_curses_panel       cmath               mimetypes           subprocess
_datetime           cmd                 mmap                sunau
_dbm                code                modulefinder        symbol
_decimal            codecs              multiprocessing     symtable
_dummy_thread       codeop              netrc               sys
_elementtree        collections         nis                 sysconfig
_functools          colorsys            nntplib             syslog
_hashlib            compileall          ntpath              tabnanny
_heapq              concurrent          nturl2path          tarfile
_imp                configparser        numbers             telnetlib
_io                 contextlib          opcode              tempfile
_json               copy                operator            termios
_locale             copyreg             optparse            test
_lsprof             crypt               os                  textwrap
_lzma               csv                 ossaudiodev         this
_markupbase         ctypes              parser              threading
_md5                curses              pathlib             time
_multibytecodec     datetime            pdb                 timeit
_multiprocessing    dbm                 pickle              tkinter
_opcode             decimal             pickletools         token
_operator           difflib             pipes               tokenize
_osx_support        dis                 pkgutil             trace
_pickle             distutils           platform            traceback
_posixsubprocess    doctest             plistlib            tracemalloc
_pydecimal          domoticz            poplib              tty
_pyio               dummy_threading     posix               turtle
_random             email               posixpath           types
_sha1               encodings           pprint              typing
_sha256             ensurepip           profile             unicodedata
_sha512             enum                pstats              unittest
_signal             errno               pty                 urllib
_sitebuiltins       faulthandler        pwd                 uu
_socket             fcntl               py_compile          uuid
_sqlite3            filecmp             pyclbr              venv
_sre                fileinput           pydoc               warnings
_ssl                fnmatch             pydoc_data          wave
_stat               formatter           pyexpat             weakref
_string             fpectl              queue               webbrowser
_strptime           fractions           quopri              wsgiref
_struct             ftplib              random              xdrlib
_symtable           functools           re                  xml
_sysconfigdata      gc                  readline            xmlrpc
_sysconfigdata_m    genericpath         reloader            xxlimited
_testbuffer         getopt              reprlib             xxsubtype
_testcapi           getpass             resource            zipapp
_testimportmultiple gettext             rlcompleter         zipfile
_testmultiphase     glob                runpy               zipimport
_thread             googlepubsub        sched               zlib
_threading_local    grp                 script__testWHR930  
_tkinter            gzip                script_device_demo
```

Comment: I'm not famililar with Domoticz - does it use some kind of virtual environment when it runs, meaning serial wouldn't be installed? Since all the others are part of python

Comment: @urbanespaceman Not that I know of. I am looking in the same direction. what is so special about this non-python serial library. Or could it be that the user who is running the script has or hasnot access to the library. If I run the script via Thonny I am user Pi. Domotics is a deamon, run by root. but if domoticz spawns a process to run the script, is that also run as root.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is `pySerial`: `python -m pip install pyserial`: https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html

Comment: @Silveris that is exactly the same package. either you install it as a debian package with apt-get install or you install it with pip. the result is the same. I've tried both installation routes.

Comment: Can you install something else (doesn't really matter what - something small) and import that in your script - see if it's specifically a serial problem. If not (which I suspect) then we're looking at something to do with the environment that your scheduler runs things in ...

Comment: @urbanespaceman:  good idea. I added the line import scipy to my script. Ran the script with Thonny to verify that the lib was not installed. got an errormessage. then I ran sudo apt-getinstall python3-scipy. Ran the script again in Thonny. no error message this time. So the lib in installed well. But when the script is started by the Domoticz scheduler the error about the serial library remains and there is no error about scipy. it looks to me it has someting to do with the serial lib.

Comment: Very odd. I'd have put money on it beinf some local env thing for demoticz :) is there any way you can run a `pip list` or something from the schedule task to see what it thinks is installed? Also dump out the env vars - the only other thing I can think of is that apt-get sets some env var for serial which isn't set when demoticz runs ... that also seems odd though.

Comment: My bad. I added import scipy below import serial. the script aborted at serial. so it never came to the scipy line. Now I deleted the serial line, I get a message on the Scipy too. so you are right it has something to do with the enviroment domoticz runs the scripts in...

Comment: the module serial is located in

Comment: the module serial is located in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/serial`. I compared the `PATH` variable. in both cases is /usr/ib not explicitly mentioned. However the 'environment' is completely different. but in neither of the environments I see a reference to the python invocation

Comment: I added a `help ('modules')` to the script. All standard modules are there exept for serial in the scheduled task but that is obvious.

Comment: @urbanespaceman, so in the mean time I fully agree that it has something to do with the environment

Comment: Thonny runs with user "pi". Domoticz scheduler runs with user "root"

Comment: Finally I found out. The serial package was installed multiple times in different locations and that caused the problem. I uninstalled, removed and purged all versions.

Comment: ``` 
pip uninstall pyserial, sudo pip uninstall pyserial, sudo apt-get --purge remove python-serial and finally sudo apt-get --purge remove python3-serial
```.
look in various install folders such as
home/pi/.local/lib/site-packages (pip installation)
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (sudo pip installation)
usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (sudo apt-get install python-serial installation)
usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (sudo apt-get install python3-serial installation)

Comment: To get things working I had to install with `sudo apt-get install python3-serial` and not the pip installer, because pip installed the python3 package in the python2.7 folders.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out. The serial package was installed multiple times in different locations and that caused the problem. I uninstalled, removed and purged all versions.
To get things working I had to install with `sudo apt-get install python3-serial` and not the pip installer, because pip installed the python3 package in the python2.7 folders.

Comment: If you invoke pip through your preferred python interpreter, e.g. `python3.9 -m pip install pyserial` it will ensure the module is installed is in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer?

```
pip install pyserial
```